# Deleting json value with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, http-delete

I have tried to many ways , but i am stuck with a simple function in javascript, and i don't know where i need to looking for ... the problem is this:

I have a Json file like this one:

```
{
  "blacklist": [
    {
      "email": "strangemail@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "strangemail1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "strangemail2@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "fianlt@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "finalstatustest@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like simple remove an email with a simple function like this one:

```
 function cancel(email) // parameter that contain the value to delete
{
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('pvt.json'); //get local json file
  let mydata = JSON.parse(rawdata); //parsing rawdata 

  var key = email; //setting up key
  delete mydata.blacklist[key]; //using delete function for delete an element

  let data = JSON.stringify(mydata, null, 2); //stringify the result
  fs.writeFileSync('pvt.json', data); // overwrite local file with new one with all changes
}
```

the problem is ... it doesn't works ... i don't know why ... i tried to read the documentation, but i didn't found any solution

Comment: What's the value of your `email` variable? It appears out of nowhere in the code. Is it a string containing the email address you want to remove?

Comment: what is this ?  var key = email; //setting up key

Comment: @T.J. Thank you for the reply! Yes, email is a string var that contain the email to delete. Sorry, i will istant update the code !

Comment: @ChandraShekhar key is the vaule to delete, email is the parameter passed in the function that contain the value to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` operator is for removing a *property* from an *object*, using the property's name. You're trying to remove an *entry* from an *array*, using the value of a property of an object in the array.

Assuming `email` is a variable containing the email address in the entry you want to remove, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is one easy way to do that:

```
mydata.blacklist = mydata.blacklist.filter(entry => entry.email !== email);
```

`filter` builds a new array from the entries in the original array that meet the criteria in the callback — in this case, that their `email` property *doesn't* match the email address you want to remove.

If you wanted to modify the array in place rather than creating a new one, you'd use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
const index = mydata.blacklist.findIndex(entry => entry.email === email);
if (index !== -1) {
    mydata.blacklist.splice(index, 1); // Remove the entry at the index
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! yes, email is the value passed as parameter that we need to remove ... and yes, i already used filter, but i don't understand how to delete the value after filtered

Comment: @Zenek - You don't have to delete it after you've filtered it out. Filtering it out is, effectively, deleting it.

Comment: TypeError: mydata.findIndex is not a function

Comment: @Zenek - Sorry, should have been `mydata.blacklist`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to use your function, but if i can, i  would like understand what did you used (i don't like copy/paste). Thank to your function we will obtain a new array called "mydata.blacklist" that doesn't have the email searched in ?

Comment: @Zenek - Right. Did you read the linked page? It explains `filter` in some detail.

Comment: yes yes i was reading .. thank you! You really helped me! It works :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete works to delete a `key-value` from an `object`. Here you have an `array of items[objects]`. You should use `filter` to remove unwanted `element`.

**Update:**

```
function cancel(selectedEmail) {
  let rawdata = fs.readFileSync("pvt.json"); //get local json file
  let mydata = JSON.parse(rawdata); //parsing rawdata
  mydata.blacklist = mydata.blacklist.filter(
    (item) => item.email !== selectedEmail.email
  );
  fs.writeFileSync("pvt.json", JSON.stringify(mydata, null, 2)); // overwrite local file with new one with all changes
}
```

**Sample:**

```js
const info = {
  blacklist: [
    {
      email: "strangemail@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      email: "strangemail1@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      email: "strangemail2@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      email: "fianlt@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      email: "finalstatustest@gmail.com",
    },
  ],
};
const selectedEmail = {email: "finalstatustest@gmail.com"}

info.blacklist = info.blacklist.filter(item => item.email !== selectedEmail.email)
console.log(info)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this one , but it doesn't works. Email rest in the array and in the json file :/

Comment: can u see what is coming in log..email. If it is not object.. then use 
`info.blacklist.filter(item => item.email !== email)`

Comment: probably is my fault... just let me understand what you did : i have added the function code that you wrote in my js server-side script. Then you have wrote a "sample" of your code, but it doesn't have the cancel function linked in to (?) so... (?)

Comment: sample is for u to run and see output working. kind of logic to understand. U write ur own server code.